# jquery check uncheck table rows except clicking child input

Tags: jquery

For a simple table, I'm trying to get this to work using jquery:

- clicking on a row checks/unchecks a child td input checkbox
- clicking on the child input checkbox itself works as well

The first works, but the second doesn't - every time I click on the checkbox itself it's doing nothing. I've tried to remove the event handler using off() but could not get it to work properly.

**HTML**

```
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>First row</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Second row</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //clicking table rows checks or unckecks boxes    
  $("#i-table tbody tr").click(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input");
    //$($checkbox).off("click");
    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shermy27/bneozk92/13/) sample.

Any advice is would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If your requirement doesn't force you to use td, you can add a label with `for` attribute referring the checkbox's id. That way you can avoid the jquery code entirely.

`<td>
        <input id="check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="check">First Row 13</label>
      </td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on `checkbox` it will trigger two events. First will be default `click` from `checkbox` and another one which you have assigned to `tr`. So you can check that if `target` is `checkbox` or not. If it is `checkbox` then do not perform `$checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));`.

You can check that with below condition.

`event.target.type != "checkbox"`

You need to add `event` parameter in callback function like below.

`$("#i-table tbody tr").click(function(event) {...}`

You complete code will be like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //clicking table rows checks or unckecks boxes    
  $("#i-table tbody tr").click(function(event) {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input");

    if (event.target.type != "checkbox") {

      //$($checkbox).off("click");
      $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="i-table">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>First row</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Second row</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: amazed by how quick this was answered and with even different solutions, really appreciate it!

Comment: I like this answer because it allows me to detect if my click target is a checkbox, I did not know how to do that. I don't quite understand the callback mechanish (checked it here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp). The `event.target.type` is new to me, i would have thought it's js syntax, but I see it's actually DOM. Much more to learn ahead it seems!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to check the already checked checkbox here(!), that makes it unchecked.

When you directly click on the checkbox, by default it will be checked, no manual triggering needed. But as you capture the tr event it gets triggered whenever you click on the checkbox also.

To avoid this, capture the event on td like,

```
$("#i-table tbody td:not(:first-child)")
```

Then to get to the input, use

```
$(this).siblings().find('input')
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6o5dc03/).

Answer (score 2):

**Try with below approach or you can detect checkbox or input click:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //clicking table rows checks or unckecks boxes    
  $("#i-table tbody tr").click(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input");
    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
  });
  
  $("#i-table tbody tr td input").click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
     $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="i-table">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>First row</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Second row</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the checkbox, click event happens on checkbox itself, and then on its parent - `td` and then `tr`. So first, input is checked, but is then unchecked immediately. The solution is to stop propagation of event when clicking on checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //clicking table rows checks or unckecks boxes    
  $("#i-table tbody tr").click(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input");
    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
  });
  $("#i-table tbody tr td input").click(function(e) {
    // prevent click event on parents
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
});
```